# Codeigniter email not working on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, codeigniter-2

My CodeIgniter application is hosted on shared hosting in the subdirectory

```
www.website.com/myapp
```

I tired Mailgun, Gmail and own shared hosting SMTP but not working on the live server please suggest me something.

Mailgun is working on localhost the rest not working on live server and localhost.

This is my Email configuration

```
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'mailpath' =>'/usr/sbin/sendmail',
'smtp_host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
'smtp_port' => 25,
'smtp_timeout' =>7,
'smtp_user' => 'postmaster@sandbox98d0b532baae4e5ab6109bd2a18ca559.mailgun.org', 
'smtp_pass' => '***********************',
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset' => 'utf-8',
'crlf' => "\r\n",
'newline' => "\r\n",
'wordwrap' => TRUE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its a shared hosting server you'll probably find they've shut traffic on port 25. If the credentials are exactly the same. I assume the mailpath is correct though?

Comment: its saying Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to mail.alhamedcharity.org:26 (Connection refused)

Comment: You connect to mail. on inbound and that setting doesn't appear in the settings you've provided?